# a problem with playing video over the internet using exoplayer

Tags: android, caching, exoplayer

How can I adjust the load control parameters of ExoPlayer to achieve continuous buffering without interruptions?

I want to make ExoPlayer buffer continuously, instead of stopping the buffering when i watch the buffered part of any video loaded from the internet

i tried to change loadcontrols but it's not what exactly i want,

i tried to change the values, parameters and classes like min_buffer, max_buffer, DashMediaSource, SsMediaSource and etc but none of them worked as i want

i have already searched on the internet for solution of this problem but i havent found any completed solution for this problem

Comment: Can you provide some code to help? Also which exoplayer version are you using?

Comment: thanks, i have already solved the problem by make my own solution